# Maven cannot find Lombok's ExtensionMethod during compilation

Tags: maven, lombok

I'm using Eclipse and I have mulitmodule Maven project in which I use Lombok(1.16.4) Java=jdk1.7.0_71.

In Eclipse all my code compiles and JUnit testes pass. However in Maven (v. 3.2.3 and 3.3.3) code does not compile.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] DetermineMarketDirection.java:[86,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sumValuesDouble(java.lang.String)
  location: variable listToWorkOn of type java.util.List<T>
[INFO] 1 error
```

This `sumValuesDouble` is my Lombok's extension method for type `List<>` which is defined in `module A`. Error above occures in `module C` which depends on `module A`.

This is part of `ExtensionList.java`:

```
public static <T> Double sumValuesDouble(List<T> list, final String methodName) {
        return sumValuesOf(list, methodName, Double.class);
    }

    private static <T, N extends Number> N sumValuesOf(List<T> list, final String methodName, Class<N> type) {

        Function<T, N> transform = new Function<T, N>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            @SneakyThrows
            public N apply(T from) {
                Method method = from.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
                return (N) method.invoke(from);
            }
        };

        List<N> projectedList = Lists.transform(list, transform);
        return sumAll(projectedList);
    }
```

It's very strange because I have tests in `Module A` for this extension method and they compile OK and pass.

Part of test from `Module A`:

```
@ExtensionMethod({ ExtensionList.class })
public class ExtensionListSumAllTest {
    @Test
    public void testDouble() {
        List<ValueDouble> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
        listDouble.add(new ValueDouble(1, 1d));
        listDouble.add(new ValueDouble(2, 2d));
        listDouble.add(new ValueDouble(3, 3d));
        Double actual = listDouble.sumValuesDouble("getValue");
        final Double expected = 6d;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public class ValueDouble {
        private final Integer id;
        private final Double value;
    }
}
```

What can I do to make Maven "see" this method?

BTW: I use a lot of extension methods in `module c` and Maven has problem with only that one. Also in this project/eclipse I use Lombok for a long time and I didn't had such problem before.

UPDATE:

I played a little bit more and I found out, that when I add 'dummy' code before execution of Extension method maven compile code wihtout problems.

So, this does not compile

```
@Slf4j
@ExtensionMethod({ ExtensionList.class })
public class SmaCalculator {
    static <C extends Candle> double calculateSMA(List<C> candles, int sma) {
        List<C> listToWorkOn = prepareListForSmaCalculation(candles, sma);

        Double sum = listToWorkOn.sumValuesOf("getClosePrice");

        Double smaValue = sum / sma;
        return smaValue;
    }
...other methods...
}
```

But this compiles SUCCESSFULLY by Maven, and `dupa` object does not even referes to `listToWorkOn` object:

```
static <C extends Candle> double calculateSMA(List<C> candles, int sma) {
    List<C> listToWorkOn = prepareListForSmaCalculation(candles, sma);

    List<C> dupa = new ArrayList<C>();
    dupa.add(listToWorkOn.first());
    dupa.sumValuesOf("getClosePrice");

    Double sum = listToWorkOn.sumValuesOf("getClosePrice");

    Double smaValue = sum / sma;
    return smaValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after switching back to 1.16.2 and it seems to work.